# Php Mysql query performance or logic improvement

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Totally out of ideas here, could be needing a simple solution that i don't see.. I need a better logic for what i am doing or some performance hints. Thank you and sorry for my English.

Ok, so here is what i am trying to do:
I have some orders(table comenzi), each order has one or more products (table croit), and some of those products are in stock (table magazie).

I want to display a list like this:
Order 1 have product 1, but product 1 can be found on other orders too, 
so for each order i search the products it has, 
and for each product from that order i search in all other orders to see if i find it, 
if i find it i search the stock to display how many of those products or similar products we have on stock, and after that i need to exclude that product, so when i reach the order that contained that specific product it will not be shown again at his order.
Here is a simple example:

```
O1 (Order 1 from table comenzi) has P1,P2,P3 (products for Order 1 in table croit ),
O2 has P2,P5,P7
O3 has P1,P2,P7


The output should be:
O1 (Order 1 name and details)
    +P1 ( O1 - some details including stock)
    -P1 ( O3 - some details including stock)
    +P2 ( O1 - some details including stock)
    -P2 ( O2 - some details including stock)
    -P2 ( O3 - some details including stock)
    +P3 ( O1 - some details including stock)
O2 (Order 2 name and details)
    +P5 ( O2 - some details including stock)
    +P7 ( O2 - some details including stock)
    -P7 ( O3 - some details including stock)
O3 (Order 3 name and details)
    - no products because they were already displayed before
```

As you see The + sign means that product is from that order and that comes in first, and then the products for the other orders..
This is the basic output i want. 
If you need more info please ask.

I have made a sqlfiddle at : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89147/1

here are the indexes, for some reason fiddle give me an error when i used them..

```
--
-- Indexes for table `comenzi`
--
ALTER TABLE `comenzi`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `croit`
--
ALTER TABLE `croit`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `croitconf`
--
ALTER TABLE `croitconf`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `codprod` (`codprod`);

--
-- Indexes for table `magazie`
--
ALTER TABLE `magazie`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `magazine`
--
ALTER TABLE `magazine`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `comenzi`
--
ALTER TABLE `comenzi`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=10313;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `croit`
--
ALTER TABLE `croit`
MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=87501;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `croitconf`
--
ALTER TABLE `croitconf`
MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=2106;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `magazie`
--
ALTER TABLE `magazie`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=2794;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `magazine`
--
ALTER TABLE `magazine`
MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=83;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

To make it simple i will add here only the sql queries and some info about how they should work:

Query 1: load a list of orders and keep the id's as array, also i keep the array in $_SESSION for pagination,

```
$query = "SELECT numar_comanda FROM comenzi where factura ='' and valoare = '' and dataplecare!='NULL' and factcorectie = '' and terminat = 0";
```

and the php:

```
while ($rowcom=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlcom)) {
    $combun[$rowcom['numar_comanda']]=$rowcom['numar_comanda'];
}
$_SESSION[combun]=$combun;
```

Query 2: Is basicaly the same query with extra fields, but this time for every order i start pulling the products to show under my order

```
$query = "SELECT comenzi.numar_comanda, comenzi.dataplecare as dataplecare, comenzi.data_emitere as dataemitere, magazine.nume as magazin FROM comenzi,magazine
where comenzi.magazine_id=magazine.id and comenzi.factura ='' and comenzi.valoare = '' and comenzi.dataplecare!='NULL' and comenzi.factcorectie = ''  and comenzi.terminat = 0
order by comenzi.dataplecare ASC ";
```

//i have a LIMIT $postnumbers OFFSET $offset but is not required, if i can manage to make it load fast i can remove the pagination

and the php

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlq)) {
//echo a row with order details
if ($_SESSION[prod] != "") $donecodfurn="and codfurn not in(" . implode(",", array_filter($_SESSION[prod])) . ")"; //add explude rule to the next query so that the products that i already used will be dropped
```

inside this while i have the next query to load all products from the curent order and loop through them:

```
$query = "SELECT croitconf.codprod as codprod,croitconf.codfurn as codfurn,croitconf.denumire as denumire,
croit.id as croitid,croit.croitconf_id as croitconfid,croit.cantitate as cantitate,croit.stare as stare
FROM croit,croitconf where croit.croitconf_id = croitconf.id and croit.stare <= 3 and croit.comenzi_id=$row[numar_comanda] $donecodfurn order by codfurn asc";
```

and the php :

```
$sqlcomanda=mysqli_query($sql, $query) or die(mysqli_error($sql));
$codfurn="";
while ($com=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlcomanda)) { //for every product of this order
    //echo a row with the product details and other info
```

inside this loop i get the info from the table magazie, that is a stock table, this has 2 options, if we have the exact product in stock (same codprod) or a similar product (same codfurn)

```
$query =  "select sum(cantitate) as cant from magazie where codfurn = '" . $com[codfurn] . "'";
```

if we have a similar product in stock display domething

```
$magq = mysqli_query($sql,$query);
$mag=mysqli_fetch_array($magq);
//echo some data about stock if $mag is array


$query = "select sum(cantitate) as cant from magazie where codprod  = '" . $com[codprod] . "'";
```

php if we have the same product in stock display domething

```
$magq=mysqli_query($sql, $query);
$mag=mysqli_fetch_array($magq);
//echo some data about stock similar if $mag is array
```

further i look at my array to see if i still have unprocessed orders to get the same product as the curent one

```
if (count($_SESSION[combun]) > 0) {

$donecom="and croit.comenzi_id IN(" . implode(",", array_filter($_SESSION[combun])) . ")"; // create a rule to search only in remaining orders

$query = "select croitconf.codprod as codprod,croitconf.codfurn as codfurn,croitconf.denumire as denumire,
croit.id as croitid,croit.comenzi_id as numar_comanda,croit.croitconf_id as croitconfid,croit.cantitate as cantitate,croit.stare as stare
FROM croit,croitconf where croit.croitconf_id = croitconf.id and croit.stare <= 2 and croitconf.codfurn=$com[codfurn] $donecom and croit.comenzi_id != '$row[numar_comanda]' order by croitconf.codprod asc";
```

and the php that display and modify the arrays in $_SESSION

```
$produse= mysqli_query($sql, $query);
while ($prod=mysqli_fetch_assoc($produse)) { //similar products as the one from the initial order
//echo something about the curent product, order number and some other infos

//i look again in our stock to see if we have this or a similar product, so basicaly the same code when we first look

    $query =  "select sum(cantitate) as cant from magazie where codfurn = '" . $com[codfurn] . "'";
    //if we find similar echo something
    $query = "select sum(cantitate) as cant from magazie where codprod  = '" . $com[codprod] . "'";
    //if we find same echo something    
} // end similat products
$_SESSION[prod][$com[codfurn]]=$com[codfurn]; // add product in array so we don't process it again
} 
} //end curent product from curent order
unset($_SESSION['combun'][$row['numar_comanda']]); //remove order from array so we won't search for products in it

} //end curent order
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of what you are trying to do instead of your code which may or may not be what you want to do.

Comment: Just for uniformity, I would make all of the query strings variables, and execute `$var = mysqli_query($con, $query)`. Obviously, change those to your variables. This is only to keep your code organized. As for performance , I find it odd that those take that long to execute. What are you running on?

Comment: You're doing nested selects in a loop. In almost all cases, that's very inefficient, and can/should be re-written a single `JOIN`ed query. e.g. if your outer table has a million records, then your inner query(ies) will be build/parsed/executed a million times. whereas with a JOIN structure, you build/parse/execute the query ONCE.

Comment: I agree with @MarcB, You should use JOIN instead of all of that.

Comment: Why would you use a session instead of a normal variable if it only stays on that page? Or you could use global variables if they will change a lot.

Comment: If you want help with a good query, please build a mockup on SQL Fiddle.  Without that, potential answerers will have too much work to do to clearly see the schema you're working with.    At least extract the queries you're running from the PHP so we can properly see what you're up to on the database side without parsing your PHP code.

Comment: I am using ajax to load data from this script and i made a pagination, $_SESSION was the best thing i found to keep track of products and orders i already displayed. I will try to use SQL Fiddle and i will clean the code a little to be more easy to read. Also i can't seem to find any solution on how to join those queries.. It seems to be too complex to do everything in one query :) for me at least..

Comment: you have a lot of code there, it's not even clear if the problem is in a query or in the PHP code itself. Can you pinpoint a query that is slow?

Comment: The slowest query execution time is about 32.57 ms, so not that much, but the problem is that i have so many of them, i am looking for a way to reduce the number of queries as  Marc B pointed out " nested selects in a loop. In almost all cases, that's very inefficient", maybe joining or something, i am working on a fiddle mockup with some data and will try to explain in my own words what i need to query, i added the php so you can understand how i build the query eliminating the id's i already used in the next loop, but maybe that can be achieved some other way...

Comment: I added a sqlfiddle and edited my post, if you need something else please ask. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't have the time to look at the full question now, but I had a quick look at the fiddle and what is missing are the indices. do you have them in your db?. at least comenzi.magazine_id, magazine.id, and comenzi.dataplecare should have them.